# Factor analysis with severly skewed ordinal data and censored ordinal data

Tags: factor-analysis, ordinal-data, censoring

I am aiming to run initial exploratory factor analysis in one sample and then confirmatory in another sample. My indicators are ordinal and so I planned to generate a polychoric correlation matrix and use this when estimating the models in R and openMx. I am aware though that the polychoric correlations assume an underlying normal distribution. Most of my variables are highly skewed (i.e., I am measuring low frequency behaviours and so there is a large preponderance of zeros) and some variables have clear right censoring (i.e., the last category is often something like "more than x times").

I am wondering whether there is any recommendations for dealing with this? I have a massive sample (15000) so is it justifiable to use the central limit theorem and not worry about the observed distribution of the indicators (and just use polychoric correlations)? Will I have biased or invalid parameter estimates if I just use the polychoric correlations anyway (could I defend this?). I am reluctant to use IRT because I believe the data is multidimensional with factors being at least reasonably correlated. I am also predicting that there is a second order factor that will explain all the correlated subfactors. I also have no firm a priori predictions about how the items will load on unidimensional factors (this is my understanding of IRT, i.e., that it assumes unidimensionality but happy to be instructed otherwise).

Any guidance or correction of me reasoning would be greatly appreciated. Is there a solution to this in R?

Cheers!

Comment: I don't think there's much (any?) relationship between the distribution of the variables and the distribution of the underlying distribution - there's no reason it can't be normal, it just means that your thresholds are at the extremes. (In addition, the polychoric correlations are, I believe, pretty robust to violations of this assumption). Especially given your sample size, I say go ahead.